# Too many indices for array | python

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I'm trying to copy arrays to a pandas Dataframe and get the error "too many indices for array".

```
temp =  pd.date_range(date_from, date_to)[:len(pr_daily)]

for index in range(len(a_id)):
    if index == 0:
        finalDataframe['date'] = temp
    finalDataframe[f'pr_{a_id[index]}'] = pr_daily[:, index]
    finalDataframe[f'gloabl_irradiance_tilted_in_kWh_per_m2_{a_id[index]}'] = rad_daily[:, index]
    finalDataframe[f'system_id_{a_id[index]}'] = a_id[index]
```

The error occurs in these lines:

```
finalDataframe[f'pr_{a_id[index]}'] = pr_daily[:, index]
finalDataframe[f'gloabl_irradiance_tilted_in_kWh_per_m2_{a_id[index]}'] = rad_daily[:, index]
```

pr_daily and rad_daily are numpy arrays of of the same length.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users...\Downloads\python_scripts\pv.py", line 277, in
>
> finalDataframe[f'pr_{a_id[index]}'] = (pr_daily[:,index])
>
> IndexError: too many indices for array

Comment: post the full traceback you get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is thrown when you try to access an array element by providing too much indices.

e.g You try to access the second dimension of a 1-dimension array.

Check the shape of `pr_daily` and `rad_daily` if they indeed are 2D arrays.

```
a = np.random.rand(5,)
b = np.random.rand(5,5)

print(f'b[:,1] :: {b[:,1]}') --> OK
print(f'{a[:,1]}') --> IndexError: too many indices for array
```

You can access a numpy array shape with the [shape attribute](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html)